# Collection of criteria that a bool CriteriaAreMet method checks

Tags: c#, types

I'm trying to design a simple skill system for a game. In each game loop I want to iterate through all the player's skills and determine whether any should advance.

I thought I'd construct something like below. I don't know what type of component to use for the list of advancement criteria in the Skill class.

I'm not married to this approach but I'm hoping to avoid writing a separate concrete class for each skill; there will be dozens, and I plan to use this as a library.

```
public class Player
{
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; }
}
```

```
public class Skill
{
    public List<???> AdvancementCriteria { get; }

    bool AdvancementCriteriaMet()
    {
        // Iterate through AdvancementCriteria
        // if any return FALSE then return FALSE
    }

    void Advance()
    {
        // Advance the skill
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if(AdvancementCriteriaMet) Advance();
    }
}
```

```
public class GameLoop
{
    Player player = new Player();

    void Loop()
    {
        foreach(Skill s in player.Skills) s.Update();
    }
}
```

EDIT for clarification: I want to be able to assert things as criteria like:

- Athletics skill: Player is jumping || Player is running || Player is swimming
- Sword skill: Player.InCombat == true && Player.Wield.WieldType == Sword
- First Aid skill: BandagesUsedCurrent > BandagesUsedPrevious

Comment: What kind of criteria will there be? It could be that your `???` is `Func<Player, Skill, Bool>` (a function taking a player and a skill, returning a boolean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a delegate, with a set of lambda expressions.

```
public delegate bool AdvancementCriterion(Player player);
public List<AdvancementCriterion> AdvancementCriteria { get; }

AdvancementCriteria.Add(p => p.Thingy > x);

if (AdvancementCriteria.All(c => c(Player))
```

Comment: So for each different skill I'd need to create a new delegate?

Comment: @Superstringcheese, you'd create a new delegate instance, but you'd only need to declare the delegate (method signature) once. An alternative to creating a delegate, would be to use a `Func` as per @Fadrian's suggestion.

Comment: @Super: You would have a separate lambda expression (`p => p.Thingy > x`) for each skill and criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Func<bool>> AdvancementCriteria { get; }
```